# Regex Pattern : not start with "www" except "admin"

Tags: xml, regex, web-config

I have a web.config rule. It supports multiple domain allies in one web.config file. It adds www. prefix and redirect automaticly.

```
<rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true"> 
       <match url=".*" /> 
       <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"> 
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" negate="true" />
       </conditions> 
       <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
     </rule>
```

But I dont want to redirect when domain starts with "admin" sub domain.

How can I, convert this regex:  ^(www.)(.*)$

Comment: (admin\.)(.*)$|^(www\.)(.*)$

Comment: ^(www.|admin.)(.*)$ is better

Answer (score 0):

First of all be careful when using ".".
It's a special character that is a substitute for "any character".
Second, you can make match branches using (aa|bb). It means "a" or "b".

Thus this should work:
 ^(www.|admin.)(.*)$